# Why the most of packet sniffer require sudo when they executing?

Tags: packet-analysis

I was just wondering why most of the packet sniffers require `sudo`?

I'm guessing that they may work at the low-level areas to sniff packets, but I'd like to know the **exact reason** for their mechanism which is the reason that requires `sudo`.

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host OSes are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packet capture requires elevated privileges for obvious reasons. (do you want any idiot to be able to watch all traffic?) The program often needs to be able to put the interface in promiscuous mode. And it needs to access a "raw" socket. Both of which are privileged functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better question for a sysadmin section of Stack Exchange, perhaps superuser.

However, **on Linux**, what you really need is `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and `CAP_NET_RAW` which are part of the capabilities system.  These can be given to users/programs without running as root; but running them as root is often the simplest way.

You can find a lot more information about this by searching for those capabilities -- CAP_NET_ADMIN / CAP_NET_RAW.